# Latest Windows UbuntuOne client not working correctly

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows

I just installed the ubuntuone 1.0-beta client because I got the email about it today.  I got all of the files I could see on the web site downloaded to my computer as expected.  I dropped a new file in the folder and did a couple connect disconnect operations and the new client says "File Sync is up-to-date."  I do not see that new file in the web interface.

Either it is not working or that up-to-date notice is in error.

What is going on here?

Comment: We'll be contacting you on Monday to go over your issues. The team is taking the weekend off...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think the best way to fix this is either if you pop in freenode #ubuntuone and ask for either of the following people:

- nessita
- alecu
- mandel (that would be me)

We probably will need to check your logs to ensure what is going on and see if the changes in your machine where indeed notified to the sync process. An other way to move forward is going on is to send a but in launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client) and attach the all the files you can find in:

C:\Users\$username$\AppData\Local\xdg\cache

The best way is to create a zip with all the different logs and attach them to the bug.

The above is for Windows 7 if you have any other version, please di file the bug and state that you do not know where to find the logs. We also need the name/path of the file you changed, otherwise is kind of hard. If you have confidential info or do not want people to know about your system do report a private bug.

Sorry I could not answer more about this, but with no logs we have no idea :(